# Finding an Injection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the set A={1/n: n$\in$$\mathbb{Z}\backslash${0}} is countably infinite.

To prove it is infinite, I said consider the set B={1/n: n$\in$$\mathbb{Z}^+$}, and note that B$\subseteq$A. Considering the function f:$\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow$B where f(x)=1/x, I can show f is a bijection, so B is equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}^+$, so B is infinite, so A must also be infinite.

Now, to show that A is countable I need to find an injection from A into $\mathbb{N}$. I'm having trouble finding one.

Comment: Note that your problem would be easier if you had a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Z$, because that would mean that $\mathbb Z$ (and $\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$) would be countable. (I'm sure you have a bijection from A to $\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$.)

Comment: Hint: If you were to try to list the integers, what would you do? Try to put the ones with the smallest sizes first.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can find a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $A$ by mapping $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$ (this would also show that it is countably infinite).  Try mapping odd numbers to negative values in $A$ and even numbers to positive ones in $A$.  E.g. $2=2(1)\to \frac{1}{1}$, $4=2(2)\to \frac{1}{2}$, $6=2(3)\to \frac{1}{3}$, etc.  Do something similar for the odds (getting mapped to negative values).